# How do you adjust a treeview control such that it comes up fully expanded?

Tags: c#, treeview

How do you adjust a treeview control such that it comes up fully expanded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [Treeview.ExpandAll()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.expandall.aspx) after you populate the treeview with items.

I do believe the API is the same for Winforms, Web forms, and WPF.